# Why debug logs are not getting printed in console and in file

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to learn logger and I have written a way to print logs on the console and file. I set the log level to DEBUG for both the handlers. DEBUG logs are not getting printed in console and in file. ERROR/WARNING levels are getting printed as expected.

Below is the code

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("log1")
fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(name)-36s %(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s")
fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fileHandler)


fileHandler1 = logging.StreamHandler()
fileHandler1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(name)-36s %(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s")
fileHandler1.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fileHandler1)

logger.debug("My name is nitesh")
```

Comment: You have set the logging level for the handlers, but not for the logger itself. Use e.g. `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to also set the level on the logger itself.

```py
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

The documentation has a nice [flowchart](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) about this.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It worked. This information is missing in many logging documentation websites like RealPython where they are only showing Warning and error because default level is warning

Comment: The python.org logging documentation is pretty good and I can only recommend to use it.